# Adding annotation from one dataframe to each row of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have dataframe df1:

```
df1 <- data.frame(variable1=sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace=T),
             variable2=sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace=T),
            correlation=runif(5, 0,1))
```

which contains the correlations among 5 variables, thus is a dataframe of 25 line (5^2) and 3 columns that looks like this

```
   df1       variable1 variable2 correlation
    1         b         b           1
    2         b         c        0.07478433
    3         b         d        0.81535674
    4         e         c        0.79187728
    5         a         e        0.97928430
```

and so on.
Another dataframe df2 (5 lines, one for each variable and 3 cols):

```
df2 <- data.frame(variable=sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace=F),
                  progr=1:5,
                  factor=sample(1:3, 5, replace=T))
```

contains some annotations/information of each of these variables. It looks like

```
df2  variable       progr   factor
1        b           1      3
2        d           2      3
3        c           3      1
4        e           4      2
5        a           5      2
```

I'd like to add in each line of the df1 the info contained in the df2 and after do some calculation.
First thing, I would like the df1 becomes (infos added for each variable):

```
      variable1 progr1 factor1 variable2 progr2 factor2 correlation
1         b         1      3       b       1       3         1
2         b         1      3       c       3       1     0.07478433
3         b         1      3       d       2       3     0.81535674
4         e         4      2       c       3       1     0.79187728
5         a         5      2       e       4       2     0.97928430
```

and then my final result expected is:

```
      variable1 variable2 correlation same_factor  distance
1         b         b      1               1        0
2         b         c      0.07478433      0        2
3         b         d      0.81535674      1        1
4         e         c      0.79187728      0       -1
5         a         e      0.97928430      1       -1
```

where:
same_factor is a dummy variable that takes value 1 if the variable1 and variable2 belong to the same factor, 0 otherwise
and distance: = progr2-progr1
Any help is more than appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `merge` to combine dataframes:

```
out <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = "variable1", by.y = "variable")
```

If you're successively merging dataframes that share column names, you need to distinguish those columns from each other. The default is to add `.x` and `.y` as suffixes, but you can specify your own suffixes using the `suffixes` argument. From your example, you wanted "1" and "2" as suffixes (e.g. `progr1` and `progr2`), so we'll specify that in our next merge:

```
out <- merge(x = out, y = df2, by.x = "variable2", by.y = "variable", suffixes = c("1","2"))
```

`ifelse` is useful for binary outputs:

```
out$same_factor <- ifelse(as.character(out$variable1) == as.character(out$variable2), 1, 0)
```

And "distance" is just calculated by subtraction:

```
out$distance <- out$factor1 - out$factor2
```